# SD card not recognized if I create second partition

Tags: external-sd, partitions, link2sd, formatting

I need to create a second partition on my SD card to use Link2SD to store apps on it, but every time I make a second partition the phone says there is no SD card at all. I've tried it a few times with FAT32, ext4 and none but the phone always says "no SD card". When I delete the second partition it works fine and I can access all the data I had saved to my SD card.

Comment: I believe the order of the partitions is significant, because Android will only try to mount the first one. Are you putting the ext4 partition second or first?

Comment: Second, and the FAT32 is set as primary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're making the second partition primary. Both partitions need to be primary, just because it's the *second* one it still is primary.

Comment: I did that on a Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro 2017 (SM-J730GM) and it still won't detect the SD card. I partitioned the card on a PC using GParted and made sure to create the second one as primary.